# how to get selected drow down list value in Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC web app it is a view with strongly typed model where a drop down is being generated / bind by model.

Below is view code:

```
@model LoanViewModel    
<form class="wrapper minheight homeloan-form border-top" id="homeloan-form" method="post" action="LeadContact" novalidate="novalidate">

<p>@Html.ValidationSummary()</p>
<p>Select an Item : @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.HomeLoanLead.Items, new SelectList(Model.HomeLoanLead.Items), "--Choose any Item--")</p>

<div class="formnav row">
            <button class="">Show Top Home Loans <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>    
        </div>
</form>
```

In model I m hardcoding options for drop down list:

```
 public List<string> Items 
    { 
        get { _items = new List<string>(); 
            _items.Add("One"); 
            _items.Add("Two"); 
            _items.Add("Three"); 
            return _items; 
        } 
    }
```

On post back I cant get what was selected value in drop down. Please guide me how to get in post action which drop down value was selected.

Comment: At the very least you need a setter on property `Items`, but you should have one property for the `SelectList` and one property for what you want to bind to (that will contain the selected values)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks, can you please explain a little how it will be done. I mean if I add a setter in Items will it get selected value ? Or if I add another property how selected value will be assign to it ? Much thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example of using `Html.DropDownFor()` to display a list of options and bind to a property:

Model

```
public class LoanViewModel
{
  [Required]
  [Display(Name="Select Item")]
  public string Item { get; set; }

  public SelectList ItemList { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  LoanViewModel model = new LoanViewModel();
  model.Item = "Two"; // this will now pre-select the second option in the view
  ConfigureEditModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(LoanViewModel model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureEditModel(model); // repopulate select list
    return View(model); // return the view to correct errors
  }
  // If you want to validate the the value is indeed one of the items
  ConfigureEditModel(model);
  if (!model.ItemList.Contains(model.Item))
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "I'm secure!");
    return View(model);
  }

  string selectedItem = model.Item;
  ....
  // save and redirect
}

private void ConfigureEditModel(LoanViewModel model)
{
  List<string> items = new List<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
  model.ItemList = new SelectList(items); // create the options
  // any other common stuff
}
```

View

```
@model LoanViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

  @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Item)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Item, Model.ItemList), "--Choose any Item--")
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Item)

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: thanks, it really worked and it is great. But if you please can guide a little more, how I can put validation ? Just to ensure user do not temper HTML and try to push a new string. Please guide where in Model I should add attribute and which attribute. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you like I can post it as a seprate question.

Comment: Do you mean adding validation that the `Item` must have a value (can't be null or empty string)?

Comment: I need to validate Item for having a value as well but another thing to Validate is m.Item only may has a value  from ItemList values. I mean here we don't have viewstate. If visitor try to temper by add some html option and then select that option from web page.

Comment: taking above example. Just want to make sure Item can have a value which was value of ItemList (One, two or three). If user try to add four as a option in html from browser source and select, it should be controlled.

Comment: I'll update answer with basic validation for `Required`. As for ensuring its one of the values in the collection, you could add a `[RegularExpression]` attribute or you could just check that the value is one of the valid items in the POST method (and if not, add a `ModelStateError` and return the view.

Comment: Highly appropriate that. Dont mean to bother you but if possible kindly give a hint what sort of [RegularExpression] it would be ? I mean how I will refer other property value in this property's regular expression. Much thanks

Comment: As far as a regex goes, `[RegularExpression("^(One|Two|Three)$")]` should do it but this is not a very flexible approach (if you ever change the collection, you would also need to change the regex)