# The ViewData item that has the key 'CategoryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to save some new posts to my database but i got an error repeatedly.. I have a class "Posts.cs" below

```
    public partial class Post
    {
        public Post()
        {
            this.Replies = new HashSet<Reply>();
        }

        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }
        public string PostContent { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Reply> Replies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and a ViewModel which i used to render a view for users to add posts

```
 public class AddPostsVM
    {
        [Display(Name = "CategoryId")]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [Display(Name="Title")]
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [Display(Name="Content")]
        public string PostContent { get; set; }

        [Required()]
        [Display(Name="Select a Category")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public List<SelectListItem>CategoriesList { get; set; }
    }
```

I used the view model to render a view with a dropdown list in the view to fetch the list of categories in the database so that when users are adding a post they can select the category they want the post to belong to

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult CreatePost()
    {
        AddPostsVM model = new AddPostsVM();
        var categories = (from c in db.Categories
                         select new
                         {
                             CategoryName = c.CategoryName,
                             CategoryId = c.CategoryId
                         }).ToList();

        model.CategoriesList = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.CategoryName,
            Value = c.CategoryId.ToString()

        }).ToList();


        return View(model);
    }
```

In my view CreatePost.cshtml I have this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostTitle, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostTitle, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostTitle, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostContent, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @*@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.PostContent, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                <textarea class="form-control" name="PostContent" id="PostContent" rows="3"></textarea>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostContent, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoriesList, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Whenever i try to add a new post to the database by using the Post action below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePost(AddPostsVM model)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var newPost = db.Posts.Create();
            newPost.PostTitle = model.PostTitle;
            newPost.PostContent = model.PostContent;
            FormsIdentity identity = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
            int nUserID = Int32.Parse(identity.Ticket.UserData);
            newPost.AuthorId = nUserID;
            newPost.CategoryId = model.CategoryId;
            newPost.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            db.Posts.Add(newPost);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Model");

        }

    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                 eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
            foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                    ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        throw;


    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I could see that the ModelState.IsValid was returning false and I got the error saying

```
The ViewData item that has the key 'CategoryId' is of type 'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.
```

Please how do i solve this?

Comment: Initialize the `model.CategoriesList` in the post action also. Then you can see the validation errors. The error you are getting occurs when `model.CategoriesList` is null and in that case framework tries to read the list from `ViewData` and that value is not expected type as specified in that error message.

Comment: @Matthew i did that but i didnt get any error except the on i set my self that if the modelstat is invalid i should get "Invalid Model". Apart from that no error

Comment: @ibnhamza, When you return the view, `model.CategoriesList` is `null` so you get that error. If you return the view, you must reassign the `SelectList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke can You help me with rewrite the code with the correct one. Will appreciate it. Been dabbling around since.

Comment: @ibnhamza, In the POST method, before the line `return View(model);`, just copy the code you have in the GET method for assigning `model.CategoriesList` i.e. `var categories = ....; model.CategoriesList = .....;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for the help, however i'm not getting that error again but i still have no luck saving the posts to the database. I set a breakpoint and i saw that ModelState.IsValid is evaluating to false.

Comment: @ibnhamza, That's because you model has a property `CategoryName` which you have marked with `[Required]` but don't render a control for it (and you shouldn't). Just remove the property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks a lot, I didnt realize. You in particular have been a whole lot of help to me in this forum. Thanks it worked.

Comment: @ibnhamza, For assigning the `SelectList`, I find it easier to refactor it to a private method as in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26812841/how-to-get-selected-drow-down-list-value-in-action/26812944#26812944) so you dont have to repeat code. Also you can simplify it to `model.CategoriesList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");` and make `CategoriesList` typeof `SelectList` rather than `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke great, you rock!!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please can you help with this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27359229/fetching-a-single-post-along-with-all-comments-relating-to-that-post-in-asp-net. Someone is currently helping me with it but i cant seem to understand him.

Comment: @ibnhamza, Added answer to other question and this one (with other question, I wasn't 100% sure if your linq-to-sql was correct so I just used linq-to-objects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `ModelState` always returns false is that property `CategoryName` has the `[Required]` attribute and you do not render a control and post back a value so its always `null` and therefore invalid. However `CategoryName` is related to the selected Category associated with you dropdown list so you should remove this property and just rely on the `CategoryId` which is bound to the dropdownlist.

The reason for the error is that when you return the view (which was always happening becuase of the issue above), you are not reassigning the value of `CategoriesList` so its `null` and `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, Model.CategoriesList, ..)` throws the exception.

To avoid repetition , you can re-factor common code into a private method (note this assumes you change `public List<SelectListItem> CategoriesList { get; set; }` to `public SelectList CategoriesList { get; set; }`)

```
private void ConfigureEditModel(AddPostsVM model)
{
  model.CategoriesList = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CategoryID", "CategoryName");
  // any other common stuff
}
```

which you can now call in the GET method and the POST method

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CreatePost()
{
    AddPostsVM model = new AddPostsVM();
    ConfigureEditModel(model);
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreatePost(AddPostsVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureEditModel(model); // repopulate select list
    return View(model); // return the view to correct errors
  }
  // Save and redirect
}
```